# how to change a background image depending on whether it is day or night android

Tags: android, image, days

I would like to know how to make a background image change depending on it is day or night in my android app.

independently when the app is opened, just it depends on whether it is night or day.

Thanks!

Comment: use system time to decide day or night

Comment: independientemete ?

Comment: @NandakishoreShetty System time isn't enough, because it depends on more things : location and date. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this

1. Using light sensor available on your handset.
2. Using phones time.

   ```
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

   if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
   }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```

Comment: I imagine it would only change the text for the image. ¿It is right?

thank you very much!

Comment: Assuming the time of the day alone means whether it's day or night is wrong. You have to take into consideration the coordinate of the user in the world, too. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get current time of your Android with AM/PM by using this,

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int a = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if(a == Calendar.AM)
   System.out.println("AM"+now.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Now again put more checks on time to set day and night, for example if you get 8:00 PM then its night, and if you get 10:00 AM then its day.

Answer (score 0):

When your application open then call below function:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
   view.setBackground(R.mipmap.img1);     
}else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
   view.setBackground(R.mipmap.img2);  
}else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
    view.setBackground(R.mipmap.img3);  
}else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
    view.setBackground(R.mipmap.img4);  
}
```

OR

If you want to change splash screen background then you need to put above code snippet at Application  class

public class ApplicationController extends Application {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
    Global.drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img1)
    }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
        Global.drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img2)
    }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
            Global.drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img3)
    }else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
            Global.drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.img4)
    }

   }

}
```

Use Global.drawable as splash screen backgorund.
Manifest:

```
  <application
        android:name=".ApplicationController"
```

Comment: Those are arbitrary values for the time-of-day, which do not always mean it's night or day or anything else. It depends on where you are and on the date. See my answer which considers both of those

Answer (score 0):

The current time doesn't tell you really if it's night or day, because in different places in the world (depends on how north/south you are) you will get night in a different hour.
Not only that, but throughout the year the time of sunset and sunrise changes a bit every day.

What you need to do is to first get the location of the device (or at least an estimate of it), and then do some calculations.

Google has posted recently ([**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133501410#comment9)) that its code to get this is available yet deprecated (because of poor performance). It actually was used for the same purpose as you wrote: setting dark/light theme based on whether it's night now or not.

Usage:

```
private void updateUi(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        TwilightCalculator twilightCalculator = TwilightCalculator.getInstance();
        twilightCalculator.calculateTwilight(System.currentTimeMillis(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        boolean isDay = twilightCalculator.state == TwilightCalculator.DAY;
        locationTv.setText("Latitude : " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude : " + location.getLongitude() + "\nIsDay?" + isDay);
    }
}
```

**Code**

AndroidX: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/TwilightCalculator.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package androidx.appcompat.app;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
/**
 * Imported from frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/TwilightCalculator.java
 *
 * <p>Calculates the sunrise and sunsets times for a given location.</p>
 */
class TwilightCalculator {
    private static TwilightCalculator sInstance;
    static TwilightCalculator getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new TwilightCalculator();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
    /** Value of {@link #state} if it is currently day */
    public static final int DAY = 0;
    /** Value of {@link #state} if it is currently night */
    public static final int NIGHT = 1;
    private static final float DEGREES_TO_RADIANS = (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);
    // element for calculating solar transit.
    private static final float J0 = 0.0009f;
    // correction for civil twilight
    @SuppressWarnings("FloatingPointLiteralPrecision")
    private static final float ALTIDUTE_CORRECTION_CIVIL_TWILIGHT = -0.104719755f;
    // coefficients for calculating Equation of Center.
    private static final float C1 = 0.0334196f;
    private static final float C2 = 0.000349066f;
    private static final float C3 = 0.000005236f;
    @SuppressWarnings("FloatingPointLiteralPrecision")
    private static final float OBLIQUITY = 0.40927971f;
    // Java time on Jan 1, 2000 12:00 UTC.
    private static final long UTC_2000 = 946728000000L;
    /**
     * Time of sunset (civil twilight) in milliseconds or -1 in the case the day
     * or night never ends.
     */
    public long sunset;
    /**
     * Time of sunrise (civil twilight) in milliseconds or -1 in the case the
     * day or night never ends.
     */
    public long sunrise;
    /**
     * Current state
     */
    public int state;
    /**
     * calculates the civil twilight bases on time and geo-coordinates.
     *
     * @param time time in milliseconds.
     * @param latitude latitude in degrees.
     * @param longitude latitude in degrees.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("FloatingPointLiteralPrecision")
    public void calculateTwilight(long time, double latitude, double longitude) {
        final float daysSince2000 = (float) (time - UTC_2000) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
        // mean anomaly
        final float meanAnomaly = 6.240059968f + daysSince2000 * 0.01720197f;
        // true anomaly
        final double trueAnomaly = meanAnomaly + C1 * Math.sin(meanAnomaly) + C2
                * Math.sin(2 * meanAnomaly) + C3 * Math.sin(3 * meanAnomaly);
        // ecliptic longitude
        final double solarLng = trueAnomaly + 1.796593063d + Math.PI;
        // solar transit in days since 2000
        final double arcLongitude = -longitude / 360;
        float n = Math.round(daysSince2000 - J0 - arcLongitude);
        double solarTransitJ2000 = n + J0 + arcLongitude + 0.0053d * Math.sin(meanAnomaly)
                + -0.0069d * Math.sin(2 * solarLng);
        // declination of sun
        double solarDec = Math.asin(Math.sin(solarLng) * Math.sin(OBLIQUITY));
        final double latRad = latitude * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS;
        double cosHourAngle = (Math.sin(ALTIDUTE_CORRECTION_CIVIL_TWILIGHT) - Math.sin(latRad)
                * Math.sin(solarDec)) / (Math.cos(latRad) * Math.cos(solarDec));
        // The day or night never ends for the given date and location, if this value is out of
        // range.
        if (cosHourAngle >= 1) {
            state = NIGHT;
            sunset = -1;
            sunrise = -1;
            return;
        } else if (cosHourAngle <= -1) {
            state = DAY;
            sunset = -1;
            sunrise = -1;
            return;
        }
        float hourAngle = (float) (Math.acos(cosHourAngle) / (2 * Math.PI));
        sunset = Math.round((solarTransitJ2000 + hourAngle) * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) + UTC_2000;
        sunrise = Math.round((solarTransitJ2000 - hourAngle) * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) + UTC_2000;
        if (sunrise < time && sunset > time) {
            state = DAY;
        } else {
            state = NIGHT;
        }
    }
}
```

Platform:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/twilight/TwilightService.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.android.server.twilight;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.icu.impl.CalendarAstronomer;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.ArrayMap;
import android.util.Slog;
import com.android.internal.annotations.GuardedBy;
import com.android.server.SystemService;
import java.util.Objects;
/**
 * Figures out whether it's twilight time based on the user's location.
 * <p>
 * Used by the UI mode manager and other components to adjust night mode
 * effects based on sunrise and sunset.
 */
public final class TwilightService extends SystemService
        implements AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener, Handler.Callback, LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG = "TwilightService";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final int MSG_START_LISTENING = 1;
    private static final int MSG_STOP_LISTENING = 2;
    @GuardedBy("mListeners")
    private final ArrayMap<TwilightListener, Handler> mListeners = new ArrayMap<>();
    private final Handler mHandler;
    protected AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private boolean mBootCompleted;
    private boolean mHasListeners;
    private BroadcastReceiver mTimeChangedReceiver;
    protected Location mLastLocation;
    @GuardedBy("mListeners")
    protected TwilightState mLastTwilightState;
    public TwilightService(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        publishLocalService(TwilightManager.class, new TwilightManager() {
            @Override
            public void registerListener(@NonNull TwilightListener listener,
                    @NonNull Handler handler) {
                synchronized (mListeners) {
                    final boolean wasEmpty = mListeners.isEmpty();
                    mListeners.put(listener, handler);
                    if (wasEmpty && !mListeners.isEmpty()) {
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_START_LISTENING);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void unregisterListener(@NonNull TwilightListener listener) {
                synchronized (mListeners) {
                    final boolean wasEmpty = mListeners.isEmpty();
                    mListeners.remove(listener);
                    if (!wasEmpty && mListeners.isEmpty()) {
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_STOP_LISTENING);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public TwilightState getLastTwilightState() {
                synchronized (mListeners) {
                    return mLastTwilightState;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBootPhase(int phase) {
        if (phase == PHASE_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            final Context c = getContext();
            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) c.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            mBootCompleted = true;
            if (mHasListeners) {
                startListening();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_START_LISTENING:
                if (!mHasListeners) {
                    mHasListeners = true;
                    if (mBootCompleted) {
                        startListening();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            case MSG_STOP_LISTENING:
                if (mHasListeners) {
                    mHasListeners = false;
                    if (mBootCompleted) {
                        stopListening();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void startListening() {
        Slog.d(TAG, "startListening");
        // Start listening for location updates (default: low power, max 1h, min 10m).
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                null /* default */, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
        // Request the device's location immediately if a previous location isn't available.
        if (mLocationManager.getLastLocation() == null) {
            if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
            } else if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
            }
        }
        // Update whenever the system clock is changed.
        if (mTimeChangedReceiver == null) {
            mTimeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Slog.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + intent);
                    updateTwilightState();
                }
            };
            final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
            getContext().registerReceiver(mTimeChangedReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
        // Force an update now that we have listeners registered.
        updateTwilightState();
    }
    private void stopListening() {
        Slog.d(TAG, "stopListening");
        if (mTimeChangedReceiver != null) {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(mTimeChangedReceiver);
            mTimeChangedReceiver = null;
        }
        if (mLastTwilightState != null) {
            mAlarmManager.cancel(this);
        }
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        mLastLocation = null;
    }
    private void updateTwilightState() {
        // Calculate the twilight state based on the current time and location.
        final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Location location = mLastLocation != null ? mLastLocation
                : mLocationManager.getLastLocation();
        final TwilightState state = calculateTwilightState(location, currentTimeMillis);
        if (DEBUG) {
            Slog.d(TAG, "updateTwilightState: " + state);
        }
        // Notify listeners if the state has changed.
        synchronized (mListeners) {
            if (!Objects.equals(mLastTwilightState, state)) {
                mLastTwilightState = state;
                for (int i = mListeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                    final TwilightListener listener = mListeners.keyAt(i);
                    final Handler handler = mListeners.valueAt(i);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listener.onTwilightStateChanged(state);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        // Schedule an alarm to update the state at the next sunrise or sunset.
        if (state != null) {
            final long triggerAtMillis = state.isNight()
                    ? state.sunriseTimeMillis() : state.sunsetTimeMillis();
            mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, triggerAtMillis, TAG, this, mHandler);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAlarm() {
        Slog.d(TAG, "onAlarm");
        updateTwilightState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Location providers may erroneously return (0.0, 0.0) when they fail to determine the
        // device's location. These location updates can be safely ignored since the chance of a
        // user actually being at these coordinates is quite low.
        if (location != null
                && !(location.getLongitude() == 0.0 && location.getLatitude() == 0.0)) {
            Slog.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:"
                    + " provider=" + location.getProvider()
                    + " accuracy=" + location.getAccuracy()
                    + " time=" + location.getTime());
            mLastLocation = location;
            updateTwilightState();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    /**
     * Calculates the twilight state for a specific location and time.
     *
     * @param location the location to use
     * @param timeMillis the reference time to use
     * @return the calculated {@link TwilightState}, or {@code null} if location is {@code null}
     */
    private static TwilightState calculateTwilightState(Location location, long timeMillis) {
        if (location == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final CalendarAstronomer ca = new CalendarAstronomer(
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        final Calendar noon = Calendar.getInstance();
        noon.setTimeInMillis(timeMillis);
        noon.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        noon.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        noon.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        noon.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        ca.setTime(noon.getTimeInMillis());
        long sunriseTimeMillis = ca.getSunRiseSet(true /* rise */);
        long sunsetTimeMillis = ca.getSunRiseSet(false /* rise */);
        if (sunsetTimeMillis < timeMillis) {
            noon.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            ca.setTime(noon.getTimeInMillis());
            sunriseTimeMillis = ca.getSunRiseSet(true /* rise */);
        } else if (sunriseTimeMillis > timeMillis) {
            noon.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            ca.setTime(noon.getTimeInMillis());
            sunsetTimeMillis = ca.getSunRiseSet(false /* rise */);
        }
        return new TwilightState(sunriseTimeMillis, sunsetTimeMillis);
    }
}
```